# Install spring plugin in Eclipse Luna

Tags: eclipse, spring, jakarta-ee, eclipse-plugin, spring-tool-suite

I downloaded Eclipse Luna and i want to install the plugin for spring
What is the difference between: Spring IDE plugin and Spring tool suite plugin?
Which one should I download?

Eclipse+Spring Tool suite plugin = Spring Tool Suite release?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Spring Tool Suite you have more tools build into your IDE and the tools are configured.

As far as STS is concerned:

> - ... comes with Maven, Spring Roo and tc Server developer edition pre-packaged and pre-configured (you can start using tc Server or
>     Spring Roo right away without the need to download or configure them
>     manually)
> - ... comes with additional components pre-installed, like the Maven Integration for Eclipse (including the Maven Eclipse integration for
>     WTP, AJDT and Groovy/Grails)

Comment: That is correct. The STS distribution comes with a lof of stuff pre-installed and ready-to-use, like the Maven integration for Eclipse, together with their WTP add-ons, AJDT tooling, and much more. You can get the same functionality installed into an existing Eclipse by installing all those parts yourself, but I would recommend to use the STS distribution to make it easier for you.

Answer (score 7):

Download the Spring tools suite from the following URL and add the extracted libraries to the WEB-INF/lib folder of your dynamic web project.

http://spring.io/tools

or else

Go to Eclipse->Help->Install New Software
Add new site as follows:

Name: SpringSource Update Site for Eclipse 4.4
URL:  http://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/update/e4.4/